# Xcode 13.2.1 package manager failed to clone repository

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

There is a problem with Xcode 13.2.1
I can't use Swift Package Manager.
Every time it ends with error - Failed to clone repository.
I tried creating a token with all permissions in my Github account, but it didn't help.
How can I fix this problem? I can't use a more recent version of Xcode yet.
[Failed to clone repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZrGX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way to handle this issue.

1. Go to the project directory in your system
2. Right-click on xc-workspace and open as show package content
3. delete `Package.resolved` file from `xcshareddata` > `swiftpm`
4. Save and Open Xocde project
5. Reset the packages cache